# how to one component value is print to another component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

**amountcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component,Input,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'appchild',
    templateUrl: './amountcomponent.component.html'


})
export class AmountComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() greetMessage: string ;


    onKey(event: any) {
        console.log(event.target.value)

    }
    ngOnInit(){

    }    
}
```

**dobcomponent.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import {AmountComponent} from "./amountcomponent.component";

    @Component({

        templateUrl: './dobcomponent.component.html'

    })

    export class DoBComponent {        
        public quantity:any;            
        childmessage : string = "I am passed from Parent to child component"        
        onquantity(event: any) {
            this.quantity = event.target.value
            console.log(this.quantity)        
        }
       }
```

Here i have mentioned my amountcomponent and also dobcomponent  i dont know  to access this.quantity from Dob.Component.ts to amountcomponent.ts.

i have mentioned Html code of amountcomponent and dobcomponent

**amountcomponent.html**

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
<h2>{{dob.date}}</h2>
```

**dobcomponent.html**

```
<input (keyup)="onquantity($event)">
```

Comment: How's the HTML of your parent component?

Comment: you're probably looking for this? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction :)

Answer (score 0):

If the components are next to each other you can creat a reference variable and input that into amountcomponent

```
<div>
  <amount [dob]="dob"></amount>
  <dob #dob></dob>
</div>
```

inside AmountComponent:

```
@Input('dob') dobComponent: DobComponent;
```

Comment: this type of code (If the components are next to each other you can creat a reference variable and input that into amountcomponent) can you briefly explain

Comment: Show me your HTML so i can give you an example based on your situation.

Comment: Now i have add my HTML above. please check it.

Comment: I thinks it's wise if you learn the basics of Angular first... We're interested in where you use your selectors